# How to loop across the screen in python?

Tags: python, loops

I want to loop across the screen using formatted output. This is my program.

```
for counter in range(0,3):
    print("{0:>3}",end="".format(counter))
```

The outcome is: `{0:>3}{0:>3}{0:>3}` but I want to it to be `1 2`.
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `.format`in the wrong place

```
 for counter in range(0,3):
    print("{0:>3}".format(counter), end="")
```

In the previous one, you were formatting the string `""`, but you wanted to format `"{0:>3}"`.

In python, the `.` (dot) operator applies to what *immediately* comes before it.

---

You also say you want the output to be `1 2`, not `0 1 2`, and if that is indeed the case you would want to start your range at 1 (`range(1, 3)`).  If you did want to start a 0, as a matter of style you should leave out the 0 (`range(3)`).